# ScrollView vs ListView Performance

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have this situation I wanted to discuss:

I have a listview that it's purpose is show 25 stores. 
For the design I want I have:

2 layouts, the first one has:
1 big photo of the store (downloaded from a database).
1 icon if the store belongs to the best rated stores list (that icon is on my app)
1 textview (downloaded string)

the second has:
3 textviews.(downloaded string)

Everytextview has a custom typeface.

As you can Imagine, this is a huge task for each item.

My main question is:

Wouldn't I get a much better performance if I downloaded everything and instead of making a listview I populate a scrollview with this data?

It might take a bit more to create the layout but probably it would be smoother scroll or am I wrong?

Comment: The first thing you could try before deciding whether you need ListView vs ScrollView is to only display the bitmap to the resolution you need (the size of the view that's on screen).

Comment: how do you measure performance btw? Is it the length of time the user has to wait before they can see data on the screen? Or is it only the amount of lagginess (quantified by FPS) when scrolling through the content? Or some combination of these and other things?

Comment: When I refered performance was more like if the scroll is more smooth

Answer (score 6):

You can do the same with `ListView` (download everything and display), but I don't think that "downloading everything" will actually bring any performance improvements (except you're talking about cache).

`ScrollView` will lead to much worse memory performance as you'll have to create and keep 25 views at once. On contrary, `ListView` reuse the same views while scrolling which will result in creating approximately as much views as it can fit on the screen.

With `ScrollView`, if dataset changes, you have to somehow repopulate your 25 views. In worst case recreating all views.

Moreover, going with `ScrollView` you'll have to deal with 25 big photos in memory at once which will probably give you nightmares for a few days.

Comment: best answer ever ! I'm complety enlighted now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, if the number of elements in the list is less than 50 and the layout is not using too much memory, then you might be better off using a scrollview.

ListView is designed for much bigger dataset, and it's designed to reduce memory usage rather than performance.  There are tons of work that Google put into it to optimize its performance.  Together with viewholder pattern and modern hardware, and the perceived performance is close to fully populated scrollview.

But again, why need Listview if the dataset is small enough that doesn't affect memory usage?  ListView is tricky to use when combined with fancy animation due to the underlying funky optimization done by Google.

Comment: Because: 1. You have to deal with 25 items from dataset in memory (including images), 2. You have to deal with 25 view hierarchies (which are not that small memory-wise as you might think). 3. You have to recreate all this stuff as soon as dataset changes. Scrolling performance is about the same, but it's harder to do animations - I agree. Hope that `RecyclerView` will solve it.

Comment: As I mentioned "if the number of elements in the list is less than 50 and the layout is not using TOO MUCH MEMORY", that's the criteria to be better off using scrollview.

While I lean to ListView myself as well for most cases, but it really depends on each case. Therefore, I gave the reasons for both usage.

And scrollview does have its benefits.

Comment: it's not clear criteria though is it? What's too much memory? Which devices does it refer to?

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned from a similar problem is that the scrollview is smoother that the listview. My case was to opt one for the navigation drawer, because smooth inflation and scrolling in the drawer has direct impact on user experience. 
I first adopted the listview but it was by no means smooth. Then I found that found [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/cf1f30b4c752f275518384a9b71404ee501fc473/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java) that google developers use scrolview instead of listview for the drawer that works smooth for me either.
But if lazy loading of the list items is what you require(not in my case), then you should go for listview.