# Which listview is better?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I created a list using `scrollview+linearlayout`. I am creating `customviews` inside `linear layout`, here is my code:

**list.xml:**

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

**In my Activity:**

```
int length = array.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject objLoop = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String driverid = objLoop.getString("driverid");
                String name = objLoop.getString("name");
                String dlnum = objLoop.getString("dlnum");
                String contact = objLoop.getString("contact");
                //INITIALIZE TABLE LAYOUT
                TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getBaseContext());
                TableLayout.LayoutParams tableparams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                //row layout params
                TableRow.LayoutParams paramsRow = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                paramsRow.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                tableparams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableparams);
                //first row
                TableRow row1 = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
                row1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                row1.setLayoutParams(paramsRow);
                row1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_border);
                TextView textDriverName, firstIndex;
                textDriverName = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                firstIndex = new TextView(getActivity());
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsTextView = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
                textDriverName.setLayoutParams(paramsTextView);
                firstIndex.setLayoutParams(paramsTextView);
                textDriverName.setText(name);
                firstIndex.setText("Driver Name");
                row1.addView(firstIndex);
                row1.addView(textDriverName);

                tableLayout.addView(row1);

                scrollcontainer.addView(tableLayout);
            }
```

Well this code is working perfectly. It is creating listview like list. 
Another approach is:

**list.xml:**

```
<Listview
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/myid" />
```

**In activity:**

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
list.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

**My question is:**

**Which one is better?**

**First approach or second approach**

I am not able to decide which one I should use. Please forgive me for my weak grammer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use listview and set listview header which is your linear layout

Comment: How many rows of data do you have?

Comment: between 1 and 100. it depends

Comment: please read the question before down vote. I have done alot of research on this topic. At the end of the day I decided to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView can scale to handle enormous numbers of list items (usually, similar items).This means if you have small numbers of items, ScrollView and ListView are not different too much. But when your app works with a huge data, by using **ViewHolder** pattern, ListView is better choice for performance. 
Please read more about scrollview vs listview [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820679/difference-between-scrollview-and-listview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245987/scrollview-vs-listview-performance).

Comment: Yes, best and easy approach

Answer (score 1):

Scrollview is ideal for screens where scrolling is required, but it is not efficient when scroll view is used to render a larger data set. Instead, you can use specialized adapter views like ListView, GridView and Recycler View (Introduced in Android Lollipop) for long lists.

ListView is an Android ViewGroup, used extensively to display the collection of data in vertical scrollable rows. The list items are automatically inserted into the list using an Adapter and Adapter pulls data from data source sources such as an array, cursor, etc.

Check out the following examples, which might help.

[Android ListView Example](https://stacktips.com/articles/android-listview-tutorial)

[Android RecyclerView Example](https://stacktips.com/articles/android-recyclerview-example)

Comment: okay. I know about listview and scrollview. I am asking that which approach is better.

Comment: Always ListView or RecyclerView are efficient then ScrollView. It comes handy with swipe gestures, memory management and  performance will be better compared to ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, use list views for the linear layout.

They work best if you have larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

As per my opinion use of Native widgets are bettor then your approach. There are I have reason for that.
Reasons :

In Your Approach :

- When you create your own view then every time you have to create same view with different data
- Index management is maintain by your self which is hard comparative to native because in native automatically index maintain.
- Also in your approach you can not reuse your view
- Addition and Deletion hard because of Index management

In other hand native widgets Benefits :

- You Just provide data and view. It automatically managed by android
- No need to handle Index
- View Reused
- Removal and Addition easy to comparative your approach
- No need too much memory when large data display because of view reusability.

So we can say that Native Approach is better. :)